# Rescaling 2D numpy array as Dense representation

Tags: python, numpy, dense-rank, rescale

I have a numpy array . I want rescale the elements in the array, so that the smallest number in array is represented by 1, and largest number in array is represented by the number of unique elements in array.

For example

```
A=[ [2,8,8],[3,4,5] ]
```

would become

```
[ [1,5,5],[2,3,4] ]
```

Comment: Almost duplicate of [python - Numpy Array Rank All Elements - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193225/numpy-array-rank-all-elements) (although that one want the maximum to have rank 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with its `return_inverse` param -

```
np.unique(A, return_inverse=1)[1].reshape(A.shape)+1
```

Sample run -

```
In [10]: A
Out[10]: 
array([[2, 8, 8],
       [3, 4, 5]])

In [11]: np.unique(A, return_inverse=1)[1].reshape(A.shape)+1
Out[11]: 
array([[1, 5, 5],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: Everything is clear to me! But, why does adding 1 at the end works? Isn't it more like an ad-hoc solution? could this be generalized?

Comment: @kmario23 Why add 1? Because OP wants the new *mapping* to start from 1 I think. That `1` could be called `start_val` and that could be the generic version?

Comment: yes the 1 only offsets the start, if you use 10, the numbering starts from 10 to (number of unique+10).

Answer (score 1):

If you're not opposed to using `scipy`, you could use [`rankdata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html), with `method='dense'` (judging by the tags on your question):

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata

rankdata(A, 'dense').reshape(A.shape)

array([[1, 5, 5],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```

Note that in your case, `method='min'` would achieve the same results, see linked documentation for more details